# User Auth with React Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm using React, Axios and Mongoose. Trying to store a user state but am having trouble with the stored `state.user` object.

When I manually enter values for `state.user`, the app works properly, however when I actually login from the site, the user object is stored in `localStorage` but is not being read properly by the app. I noticed I had to remove `new ObjectId` from the object and also convert the `createdAt` and `lastUpdated` dates into strings in order for my static values to work. How can I get around this? Thanks!

[Screenshot of localStorage object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufneg.png)

**context.js**

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
    isFetching: false,
    error: false,
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

    useEffect(() => {
        JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem("user", state.user));
    }, [state.user]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                user: state.user,
                isFetching: state.isFetching,
                error: state.error,
                dispatch,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

**reducer.js**

```
const AuthReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "LOGIN_START":
            return {
                user: null,
                isFetching: true,
                error: false,
            };
        case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
            return {
                user: action.payload,
                isFetching: false,
                error: false,
            };
        case "LOGIN_FAILURE":
            return {
                user: null,
                isFetching: false,
                error: true,
            };
        case "FOLLOW":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: {
                    ...state.user,
                    following: [...state.user.following, action.payload],
                },
            };
        case "UNFOLLOW":
            return {
                ...state,
                user: {
                    ...state.user,
                    following: state.user.following.filter(
                        (following) => following !== action.payload
                    ),
                },
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
export default AuthReducer;
```

**actions.js**

```
export const LoginStart = (userCredentials) => ({
    type: "LOGIN_START",
});

export const LoginSuccess = (user) => ({
    type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
    payload: user,
});

export const LoginFailure = (error) => ({
    type: "LOGIN_FAILURE",
    payload: error,
});

export const Follow = (userId) => ({
    type: "FOLLOW",
    payload: userId,
});
export const Unfollow = (userId) => ({
    type: "UNFOLLOW",
    payload: userId,
});
```

**utils/api.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

export const loginCall = async (userCredentials, dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_START" });
    try {
        const response = await axios.post("/api/auth/login", userCredentials);
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS", payload: response.data });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: "LOGIN_FAILURE", payload: error });
    }
};
```

Comment: first bug I see is useEffect(() => {
        JSON.stringify(localStorage.setItem("user", state.user));
    }, [state.user]);  change it to useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
    }, [state.user]);

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried that and it is now a string in localStorage but still having the same issue.

Comment: I figured out my own issue here. the problem was in my route. I was returning a string instead of the user object.

res.status(200).json(user);

instead I had

res.status(200).json(`user has logged in at ${Date.now()}`)